# why is this code not work properly?

Tags: javascript

in this code when click on any radio button only image3.jpg show , in second click there is no change.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('rbpic');

for (var i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click" , changepic );
}

function changepic() {
    var c = document.getElementById("image") ;

    for (var j=0 ; j<a.length ; j++)  {   
        var d = a[j].value ;

        if(d === "one") { 
            c.src = "image1.jpg";
        }
        else if (d === "two") { 
            c.src = "image2.jpg";
        }
        else if (d === "three") { 
            c.src = "image3.jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gaurav Please include your HTML so we can help you more. Thanks!

Comment: i want just add one function on all three radio buttons .

Comment: Oh, I see your problem now! Instead of having the `for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++)`, just use `this` to get the radio button that was clicked. Code snippet coming up!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the `changepic()` function: You're looping through every radio button and setting the corresponding image when any of the radio buttons changes.

My two solutions:

1. Get rid of the loop and replace `a[j].value` with `e.target.value`:

   ```
   function changepic(e) {
       var c = document.getElementById("image");
       var d = e.target.value;
       if (d === "one") {
           c.src = "image1.jpg";
       } else if (d === "two") {
           c.src = "image2.jpg";
       } else if (d === "three") {
           c.src = "image3.jpg";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Loop through all of the radio buttons and see which one is checked:

   ```
   function changepic() {
       var c = document.getElementById("image");
       for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
           if (a[j].checked) {
               var d = a[j].value;
               if (d === "one") {
                   c.src = "image1.jpg";
               } else if (d === "two") {
                   c.src = "image2.jpg";
               } else if (d === "three") {
                   c.src = "image3.jpg";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the radio button that was clicked in the event handler, use `this`:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('rbpic');

for (var i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click" , changepic );
}

//We declare c on the outside so we're not calling document.getElementById() on every single click:
var c = document.getElementById("image") ;
function changepic() {
    //Get the value of this radio button:
    var d = this.value ;
    //Execute the following as normal:
    if(d === "one") { 
        c.src = "image1.jpg";
    }
    else if (d === "two") { 
        c.src = "image2.jpg";
    }
    else if (d === "three") { 
        c.src = "image3.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is in `changepic` the context of the radio button clicked. So `this.value` is the value of the radio button.

Comment: Yes, `this.value` is the value of the radio button. Isn't that what the questioner wanted?